# What is the left join that equals this righ join?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, right-join

Thanks first.

I have this right join worked fine, but when I try to change it into a left join I got an error.

The question is to get all information about the students from table Student who has higher score in class1 than class2 from a score-student table called SC.

**Student(SId,Sname,Sage,Ssex)**

**SC(SId,CId,Score)**

Here is my RIGHT JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM Student RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT t1.SId, class1, class2 FROM
      (SELECT SId, score as class1 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '01')AS t1,
      (SELECT SId, score AS class2 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '02')AS t2
    WHERE t1.SId = t2.SId
    AND t1.class1 > t2.class2
    )r 
ON Student.SId = r.SId;
```

And then I tried something like:

```
SELECT t1.SId, class1, class2, Student.* FROM
    (SELECT SId, score as class1 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '01')AS t1,
    (SELECT SId, score AS class2 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '02')AS t2
    WHERE t1.SId = t2.SId
    AND t1.class1 > t2.class2
)r
LEFT JOIN Student
ON Student.SId = r.SId;
```

but it didn`t work.

I am pretty new with SQL, wish you could explain a little bit.

I am using MySQL5.7

Comment: You got an error/it didn't work. *Details* of this error or failure would greatly enhance this question. If there was an error, the *actual error message*, if it didn't work in some other way - what *happened* versus what you expected? We don't have your data, we can't run these queries.

Comment: What didn't work is `SELECT t1.SId`. If you want an equal select you should keep it `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: Read this excellent article on sql joins; [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Comment: You should ask *another* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are doing.  There may be a simpler approach.

Comment: Your question is answered by reading definitions of left & right join. You have *some idea* because you tried to convert. Switching left & right arguments while switching "left" with "right" leaves a result the same. But you *didn't* swicth arguments--look closely at what you did. What would be helpful is if you explained what you thought you were accomplishing. Also, please read & act on [mcve]. PS Better code formatting would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first query that works is here:**

```
SELECT * FROM Student RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT t1.SId, class1, class2 FROM
      (SELECT SId, score as class1 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '01')AS t1, 
      (SELECT SId, score AS class2 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '02')AS t2
      WHERE t1.SId = t2.SId
      AND t1.class1 > t2.class2
    )r 
ON Student.SId = r.SId;
```

The table `r` is being created via this sub-query:

```
SELECT t1.SId, class1, class2 FROM
  (SELECT SId, score as class1 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '01')AS t1, 
  (SELECT SId, score AS class2 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '02')AS t2
WHERE t1.SId = t2.SId
AND t1.class1 > t2.class2
```

`t1.Sid`, `class1` and `class2` are resolved without ambiguity. `t1.Sid` becomes available as `r.Sid` in the join `Student.SId = r.Sid`. Hence, the query works.

**The second query that causes problem is here:**

```
SELECT t1.SId, class1, class2, Student.* FROM
   (SELECT SId, score as class1 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '01')AS t1, 
   (SELECT SId, score AS class2 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '02')AS t2
  WHERE t1.SId = t2.SId
  AND t1.class1 > t2.class2
)r
LEFT JOIN Student
ON Student.SId = r.SId;
```

There are two issues to be addressed:

- Issue 1: `Student.*` is not resolved since the FROM section does not have any reference to it.
- Issue 2: Table `r` is not getting constructed correctly.

**The two issues when addressed result in this modified second query, which works:**

```
SELECT * from 
  (SELECT t1.SId, class1, class2 FROM
     (SELECT SId, score as class1 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '01')AS t1,
     (SELECT SId, score AS class2 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '02')AS t2
    WHERE t1.SId = t2.SId
    AND t1.class1 > t2.class2
  )r
LEFT JOIN Student
ON Student.SId = r.SId;
```

Comment: We must just find the arguments of the right join & swap them. You don't make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, If you have a right join query:

```
SELECT select_statement
FROM table1 
RIGHT JOIN table2 
ON join_condition;
```

You just change it to left join query like this:

```
SELECT select_statement
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1
ON join_condition;
```

For your case, when you changed your query to left join, you changed the select_statement, and it make error.

Just apply the above to your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (
    SELECT t1.SId, class1, class2 
    FROM
        (SELECT SId, score as class1 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '01') AS t1, 
        (SELECT SId, score AS class2 FROM sc WHERE sc.CId = '02') AS t2
    WHERE t1.SId = t2.SId
        AND t1.class1 > t2.class2
) r 
LEFT JOIN Student
ON Student.SId = r.SId;
```

Comment: The "general" statement is true for two tables.  It does not general to more than two tables.